# Image is not displaying until we refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http-get

In my application, when we logged in I am passing an Http get request for an image. The image is being loaded successfully but it is not displayed until I refresh the page.

I want it to be displayed when I logged in by using angular in my application.

`<img ng-src="{{ProfileImage}}" />`

This is the HTTP call:

```
  $http.get('URLpath')
    .then(function(response){
$scope.ProfileImage=response.data;
}
```

The image is getting loaded from the source but it is not displayed immediatley when i log in.

It is displayed after refreshing the page.

Comment: What is the value of `response.data` ?

Comment: Can you inspect and see that ng-src resolves to the url correctly after user logins and you call is completed ?

Comment: It is a Blob image @rayon

Comment: The ng-src is giving empty, but when I am printing the response data to console I am getting the data. @ vinod

Comment: @SIVABELLALA looks like an binding issue can u just try {{ProfileImage}} on your view somewhere to see if the value is reflected ?

Comment: add a timeout around `$scope.ProfileImage = response.data` and try.

Comment: Try this `then(function (response) { 
        $timeout(function(){$scope.ProfileImage = response.data;},100)
    }` you should inject `$timeout` in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the response guys.
This issue is fixed by storing the image to window local storage and then accessing it using angular {{ProfileImage}}.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.myObj = { 
        "image":"https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg", 
    };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DemoCtrl"> 
<img src="{{myObj.image}}"  width="100" height="100">

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either wrap your image to `ng-if` so it should appear after the data is loaded or assign some valid data to `$scope.ProfileImage` before response comes. Otherwise, your `ng-src` is neglected.